# Hibernate attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserDetails userDetails;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_details")
public class UserDetails {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    public UserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        user.setUserDetails(this);
    }

}
```

It works if I create a user with a userDetails. But then it creates a UserDetails row and I don't want it. I have to fetch a User from database and add a UserDetails later:

```
userRepository.findOneById(id).map(user -> {
    UserDetails userDetails = user.getUserDetails();
    if (userDetails == null)
        userDetails = new UserDetails(user); 
     userDetails.setEmail(email);
     userRepository.save(user); //error here
});
```

Error

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.app.domain.UserDetails.user]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.app.domain.UserDetails.user]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `UserDetails` object in this case is the owning side of the relationship between a `User` and the `UserDetails`

Bidirectional relationships between managed entities will be persisted based on references held by the owning side of the relationship.

Therefore, when you say `userRepository.save(user)`, you're actually trying to save from the child side of the relationship.

You need to create a `UserDetailsRepository` and invoke the save from that new object.

i.e. here's what the code should look like:

```
userRepository.findOneById(id).map(user -> {
    UserDetails userDetails = user.getUserDetails();
    if (userDetails == null)
        userDetails = new UserDetails(user); 
     userDetails.setEmail(email);
     userDetailsRepository.save(userDetails);
});
```

Comment: I wonder, why UserDetails is in this case the owning side? Usually it tends to be User (in this example), as specified by "mappedBy".

Comment: How do I make User side as owning ?

Answer (score -3):

the answer of was very helpful to me, is tricky to understand how hibernate works... at least for me (nooby :D)

Comment: You use the comment function to  comment the helpful answer (or simply upvote)